# How to find a file in AWS s3 based on pattern matching

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ls

I have a requirement to find a file in AWS s3 based on pattern matching as below - 
temp=`aws s3 ls s3://<bucket_name><path to file>/abc_[[0-9]][[0-9]][[0-9]][[0-9]]-[[0-9]][[0-9]]-[[0-9]][[0-9]]_[[0-9]][[0-9]][[0-9]][[0-9]]-[[0-9]][[0-9]]-[[0-9]][[0-9]].csv`

Actual file name on S3 - 
abc_2018-07-01_2018-07-30.csv

Output i want to get is as below -

2018-07-12 13:27:47 0 src_pap_search_results_log_2018-07-01_2018-07-31.csv

Comment: are you talking about achieving this using linux command line utilities or some kind of programming language?

Answer (score 3):

You need to pipe the result of your s3 command to `grep` and use regex.

```
aws s3 ls s3://<bucket_name> | grep -e 'abc_.*'
```

to limit it only to to csv files in every path, issue

```
aws s3 ls s3://<bucket_name> --recursive | grep '.csv' | grep -e 'abc_.*'
```

Modify the grep's regex string to match the files you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws s3 ls` command, pipe it through `grep` and provide your regex pattern.